# make fail building application for Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I'm under Windows 7 using Cygwin. I'm following this tutorial http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html.
Everything's fine until I run the make command:

```
make APP=ndk_demo
```

this is the output:

```
$ make APP=ndk_demo
Android NDK: Building for application 'ndk_demo'
Compile thumb  : ndk_demo <= ndk_demo.c
/bin/sh: ./out/apps/ndk_demo/armeabi/objs/ndk_demo/ndk_demo.o.d: No such file or directory
build/core/build-binary.mk:240: recipe for target `out/apps/ndk_demo/armeabi/objs/ndk_demo/ndk_demo.o' failed
make: *** [out/apps/ndk_demo/armeabi/objs/ndk_demo/ndk_demo.o] Error 127
make: *** Eliminazione del file "out/apps/ndk_demo/armeabi/objs/ndk_demo/ndk_demo.o"
```

I can't figure out the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the NDK are you using? If you are using a fairly recent version you should be using *ndk-build*. See $(NDK)/docs/NDK-BUILD.html for info.

Comment: Thank you, it worked using ndk-build. I had to move the jni folder up to one level, near the Application.mk, though

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with NDK r4, it is recommended to put the Application.mk file in the jni folder; see $(NDK)/docs/HOWTO.html:

'Starting with NDK r4, you can simply place the file under $PROJECT/jni/
and launch the 'ndk-build' script from your project tree.'